# css two div floated left . Right div not covering the remaining space

Tags: css

I've two divs leftSide and rightSide whose parent is innerContainer. I've floated both the divs to left.They are appearing side by side but the right div is not covering the remaining space of the parent div.

I tried using overflow:hidden and also specified the width but still it is of the same width.

My Css:

```
  #container {
  overflow:auto;
  margin:10px auto;
}

   #innerContainer{
        margin:10px auto;   
        width:1200px;
        background:#FFFFFF;
        border:2px solid #09F;
        overflow:auto;
}

 #leftSide{
overflow:auto;
float:left;
width:700px;
border:3px solid #F00;
 }

 #topheaderProfile{
margin:5px;
border:1px solid #F00;
  }

   #middleCompanyDescription{
margin:5px;
border:1px solid #333;
  }

  #Profile{
text-align:left;
  }

 .ProfileBox{
padding:10px;
cursor:pointer;
overflow:hidden;
text-align:left;
word-break:break-all;
word-wrap:break-word;
 }

 .CompanyLogo{
float:left;
padding:5px;
 }

 .rightCover{
overflow:auto;
padding:1px;
 }

  .companyTitle{
color:#36F;
font-size:24px;
overflow:hidden;
 }

 .companyTitle a{
text-decoration:none;
 }

 .CompanyRating{
float:left;
margin-top:3px;
 }

 .Companylikedicon{
overflow:hidden;
float:right;
margin-left:10px;
 }

.Companycommenticon{
float:right;
margin-right:10px;
}



.CompanySlogan{
color:#999;
word-break:break-all;
word-wrap:break-word;
clear:both;
 }



  #rightSide{
width:100px;
border:1px solid #000;
  }
```

My Html:

```
  <div id="container">
     <div id="innerContainer">

           <div id="leftSide"> 

        <div id="topheaderProfile">
            <div id='Profile'>
                <div class='ProfileBox'>
                    <div class='CompanyLogo'><img src='../Images/defaultPic.jpg' width='90' height='90'/></div> 
                    <div class='rightCover'>
                        <div class='companyTitle'>My Company</div>
                        <div class='CompanyRating'>
                                            Rating : <img src='../Images/FilledStar.png' width='20' height='20' id='Star1' />       
                                            <img src='../Images/EmptyStar.png' width='20' height='20' id='Star2' />
                                            <img src='../Images/EmptyStar.png' width='20' height='20' id='Star3' />
                                            <img src='../Images/EmptyStar.png' width='20' height='20' id='Star4' />
                                            <img src='../Images/EmptyStar.png' width='20' height='20' id='Star5' />
                         </div>

                         <div class='Companylikedicon'><img src='../Images/LikedIcon.png'  width='25' height='25' /> 100</div>
                         <div class='Companycommenticon' ><img src='../Images/comment.png'  width='25' height='25' /> 100</div>

                         <div class='CompanySlogan'>This is the best offer you get 2Rs. off in the besaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaat underwear of the worldffer you get 2Rs. off in the besaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaat underwear of the world.</div>
                   </div>

               </div>    <!--ProfileBox-->
            </div>
           </div><!--TopHeeaderProfile-->

    <div id="middleCompanyDescription">
sadasdsad
    </div>




         </div>     <!--LeftSide-->


        <div id="rightSide">
          sadasdasdasd
        </div>


     </div>


 </div>
```

Ok I've found the problem.There is another css file containing id names same as in this file.This is causing the problem.The properties of that file are being applied here.
Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: Floating items need to have a specified WIDTH.

Comment: you can see that i've specified width for both the items.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried using overflow:hidden and also specified the width but still it is of the same width.

Use `overflow: hidden` but don't specify any `width` if you want `#rightSide` to fill the remaining space.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/Yuxzs/

```css
#rightSide {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}​
```

Comment: I mean that i've used both the options one by one but none of them is working.

Comment: your code is working in the fiddle but as i do the same thing.It doesn'nt work there.

Comment: Which browser are you testing in? Can you make a [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) demo showing how your code doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<style type="text/css">
#rightSide {
 width:100px;
 border:1px solid #000;
 float:left;
}
</style>
```

Comment: if u want leftSide  and rightSide side my side then above code works for me... try to put width in #rightSide...

Comment: the problem is that the above code works for me also always.But right now the same thing is not working and I think it is something else that is not letting it to cover the space and I am not able to figure that out.

Comment: try float:left !important; once

Comment: why dont u try putting <div style="clear: both;"></div> above <div id="container">